# How do I output 24-bit depth tiff images？

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, tiff

I used html2canvas to generate canvas and canvas-to-TIFF to convert canvas to tiff. Now the output image bit depth is 32, what should I do to output tiff image with 24-bit depth.

I'm trying to get answers from gpt, but it keeps popping up with weird bugs...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcMtz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlHoI.png)

github: https://github.com/leewakin/tiff-demo

Comment: Windows Image Properties shows the total number of bits per pixel. Given that, I assume your .tiff image is 8-bit depth with 4 channels (RGBA), which makes a total count of 8*4=32 as it is displayed in the properties

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you may have hardware capable of handling 30-bit color! :)

But anyway, to manually set the canvas' gamut (color space) you can do this...

```
let context = canvas.getContext('2d',{colorSpace:'srgb'}); // 24 bit


let data = new ImageData(0,0,{colorSpace:'srgb'}); // 24 bit
```

...and so forth. This excellent **Webkit** page explains everything in more detail...

https://webkit.org/blog/12058/wide-gamut-2d-graphics-using-html-canvas/